# Why does filtering by PK runs so much slower than filtering by another field?

Tags: performance, linq

I have two otherwise identical queries except on one of the where clause.

```
Table A : lookup table, 10 rows
Id (int, PK, auto increment, clustered index)
Name (varchar(500), non-clustered index)

Table B : slowly growing table, 1,000 rows 
A_Id (int, FK into A, no index)
Name (varchar(9), no index)
...

Table C : fastly growing table, 2,000,000 rows 
Name (varchar(9), part of PK)
...


The slow query takes 45 seconds:
select * from A
inner join B on A.Id = B.A_Id
inner join C on B.Name = C.Name
where A.Id = 4 and 
    ... some conditions on C ...

The fast query takes less than 1 second:
select * from A
inner join B on A.Id = B.A_Id
inner join C on B.Name = C.Name
where A.Name = 'SomeName' and 
    ... some conditions on C ...
```

I may not be providing the right information because I don't understand what the problem is.

I understand that an clustered index is not always faster than a non-clustered index.  Not sure whether it applies to this situation because the lookup table only has 10 rows, and the lay out of the rows shouldn't have much impact on the inner join.

It could be the where clauses for C interacts with the where clause on A in a negative way?

Any idea helps, thanks.

UPDATE 1:
The queries are generated from Linq.  They actually perform equally fast.  It appears the problem is with Linq, not Sql.

Comment: Please show the execution plans of each query.

Comment: @Tony Your comment helps.  This question is no longer related sql-server.

Comment: Then I suggest you edit or delete this question as it is still tagged 'SQL server'

Comment: I supposed it now boils down to why an int comparison is faster than a string comparison.  An int comparison is directly supported by the processor, takes a fraction of a nanosecond.  String comparisons of course are not.  Creating indexes on the WHERE clause to make it somebody else's problem.  And a heckofalot faster.